# JPA call to MSSQL stored procedure returns duplicate records

Tags: java, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-boot, named-query

There is a stored procedure in MS SQL server database which I'm calling using JPA. Calling it from the java code, it returns duplicate records:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;

@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "ClassRP.getPs",
            query = "{call Load_Ps_Data("
                    + ":param1,"
                    + ":param2,"
                    + ":param3,"
                    + ":param4)}",
            resultClass = ClassRP.class),

    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "ClassRP.getRSPs",
            query = "{call Load_RSPs_Data("
                    + ":param1,"
                    + ":param2)}",
            resultClass = ClassSP.class)
})

@Entity
@IdClass(RPKey.class)
public class ClassRP {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column1")
    private long column1;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column2")
    private int column2;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column3")
    private int column3;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column4")
    private int column4;

    public long getColumn1() {
        return column1;
    }

    public int getColumn2() {
        return column2;
    }

    public Date getColumn3() {
        return column3;
    }

    public String getColumn4() {
        return column4;
    }
}

import java.io.Serializable;

public class RPKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 41627806516297462433L;

    public Long column1;
    public Integer column2;
}

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;

@Entity
@IdClass(RPKey.class)
public class ClassSP {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column1")
    private Long column1;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column2")
    private Integer column2;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column3")
    private String column3;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "column4")
    private String column4;

    @Column(name = "column5")
    private Date column5;

    @Column(name = "column6")
    private String column6;

    @Column(name = "column7")
    private Double column7;

    public Long getColumn1() {
        return column1;
    }

    public Integer getColumn2() {
        return column2;
    }

    public Date getColumn3() {
        return column3;
    }

    public String getColumn4() {
        return column4;
    }

    public Double getColumn5() {
        return column5;
    }

    public Double getColumn6() {
        return column6;
    }

    public Double getColumn7() {
        return column7;
    }
}

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface RPsRepository extends JpaRepository<ClassRP, String> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<ClassRP> getPs(
            @Param("param1") Integer param1,
            @Param("param2") Integer param2,
            @Param("param3") Date param3,
            @Param("param4") Integer param4);

    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<ClassSP> getRSPs(
            @Param("param1") String param1,
            @Param("param2") Integer param2);
}
```

Calling the stored procedure from the MS SQL server returns the correct result:

```
exec Load_RSPs_Data param1, param2;
```

Any suggestions why the JPA call is behaving incorrectly?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("rService")
public class RService {

    @Autowired
    private RPsRepository rpsRepository;

    public List<ClassSP> getSPsData(String param1, Integer param2) {
        return rpsRepository.getRSPs(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had gone through the same issue and uncovered the problem.

You have been mentioned the identity annotation `@Id` for almost all attributes in `Entity` class. Please mention the identity annotation `@Id` only to the attribute/attributes that are unique in the resultset. This solved my problem.